# Russian short story about a person who can't inhabit time and another who can't inhabit space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for science fiction short story. It was part of a collected work from various Russian science-fiction writers. I think the book was called "Eternal Spring".

Plot: Two individuals plan to meet; however, one cannot inhabit time while the other cannot inhabit space.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.